# Android custom RxJava multiple calls

Tags: java, android, firebase, retrofit, rx-java

I just recently have started to use RxJava, and I have a problem that I need to get data from 2 different firebase json arrays. Here are my json files:

```
    { "userId" : {
"category_list" : [ {
"cat_name" : "Contacts"
}, {
"cat_name" : "Home"
}]}}

{ "Shopping" : {
"category_list" : [ {
"cat_name" : "Clothes"
}, {
"cat_name" : "Equipment"
}]}}
```

Here is my POJO for both json

```
public class CategoryList implements Serializable {
private List<Category> categoryList;

public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
    return categoryList;
}

public void setCategoryList(List<Category> categoryList) {
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
}
```

}

Here are API calls of retrofit:

```
    @PUT("/userData/{userId}.json")
        Observable<CategoryList> insertData(@Path("userId") String userId, @Body CategoryList userArray);

    @GET("/userData/{userId}.json")
        Observable<CategoryList> getUserCategories(@Path("userId") String userId);

    @GET("/adminData/Shopping.json")
        Observable<CategoryList> getAdminCategories();
```

I have already created a flatmap rxjava, which firstly calls *insertData* from retrofit and when calls *getUserCategories* from the same database, but what I need also is to call *getAdminCategories* on the same object (POJO) and use the same adapter for this. That means I need the code below to call and merge(?) two data sources on 1 recyclerView Does anyone know, how can I do this on the code below? Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void postArrayAndGetCategories(final String userId, CategoryList userArray) {
 subscription= dataManager.insertData(userId, userArray)
         .flatMap(new Func1<CategoryList, Observable<CategoryList>>() {
             @Override
             public Observable<CategoryList> call(CategoryList categoryList) {
                 // code to save data from service A to db

                 // call service B
                 return dataManager.getUserCategories(userId);
             }
         })
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(new Observer<CategoryList>() {
             @Override
             public void onCompleted() {
             }

             @Override
             public void onError(Throwable e) {
                 Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                 mainView.showError(e.toString());
             }

             @Override
             public void onNext(CategoryList categoryList) {
                 mainView.showCategoryList(categoryList); // here I use adapter
             }
         });
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to try RxFirebase library to make easier work with RxJava and Firebase together: https://github.com/FrangSierra/Rx2Firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy, if you want to merge two sources, just use [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator.

```
    dataManager.getAdminCategories().mergeWith(dataManager.insertData(userId, userArray)
            .flatMap(new Func1<CategoryList, Observable<CategoryList>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<CategoryList> call(CategoryList categoryList) {
                    // code to save data from service A to db

                    // call service B
                    return dataManager.getUserCategories(userId);
                }
            }))
```

Comment: Alexander Perfilyev, thank you for your answer, but it seems error. When I launch my activity getAdminCategories shows result for a second, but I after getUserCategories is called it just dissapears... This is because of mergeWith or something is wrong with my adapter?

Comment: Yes, it might be because you are clearing your old adapter data, when you are adding new items. Try DiffUtil or SortedList for your adapter. Another way to mitigate it would be adding .toList(). This way you will get only one onNext() call.

Comment: Great, you are amazing! Thank you